# Using if statements with jinja

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I am passing in results to my HTML file, which contains a tuple and each of the elements in the tuple is a dictionary. The row element contains five fields, one of which is url. I want to insert a different image for each element in row based on its url field. I also passed in three different url variables to my HTML file, each containing one of the possible urls as a string. Can I use jinja if statements to check equality of two strings (one being the value of the url field in rows and the other being the value of the url variables I pass into the file)?

```
<div>
{% for row in rows %}
    {% if (row.url = trumba_url) %}
        <img class="icon" src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/529755616571432960/uAELf1Xz_400x400.png'></img>
    {% endif %}
    {% if (row.url = ilab_url) %}
        <img class="icon" src='https://yt3.ggpht.com/-9SPiNJ7tggM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/6IQqBohqQ-A/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg'></img>
    {% endif %}
    {% if (row.url = hbs_url) %}
        <img class="icon" src='http://www.davidkhurst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Harvard_shield-Business.png'></img>
    {% endif %}
    <p class="event-title"><a href='{{ row.url }}'>{{ row.title }}</a></p>
    <p class="event-date">{{ row.date }}</p>
    <p class="event-location">{{ row.location }}</p>
    <br></br>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

In my python file which runs the website using flask, I have this as well as some more code that defines the tuples in results[].

```
trumba_url = 'http://www.trumba.com/events-calendar/ma/boston/harvard-events/harvard-event-calendar/harvard-activities/gazette'
ilab_url = 'https://i-lab.harvard.edu/events/'
hbs_url = 'http://www.hbs.edu/mba/admissions/admissions-events/Pages/default.aspx'

return render_template("index.html", results=results, trumba_url=trumba_url, ilab_url=ilab_url, hbs_url=hbs_url)
```

Comment: You should include what the results are of your tests, if you're not getting what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality operator (a [comparison operator](https://docs.python.org/2.4/ref/comparisons.html)) in python is `==`; `=` is an [assignment operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html). Thus, the comparison conditional should be:

```
{% if (row.url == trumba_url) %}
```

...otherwise the value of *trumba_url* would be assigned to *row.url*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{% if row.url == trumba_url %}`.